# How to display and use sort by filters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, filter

I'm still pretty new to coding and tried to find all over the internet a way to display and make use of my filter api.

I have created these filters:

```
 export const filterDataBuy = [
    {
        items: [
            { name: '150,000', value: '150000' },
            { name: '200,000', value: '200000' },
            { name: '250,000', value: '250000' },
            { name: '300,000', value: '300000' },
            { name: '350,000', value: '350000' },
            { name: '400,000', value: '400000' },
            { name: '450,000', value: '450000' },
            { name: '500,000', value: '500000'},
        ],
        placeholder: 'Min Price(USD)',
        queryName: 'minPrice',
    },
    {
        items: [
            { name: '500,000', value: '500000' },
            { name: '550,000', value: '550000' },
            { name: '600,000', value: '600000' },
            { name: '650,000', value: '650000' },
            { name: '700,000', value: '700000' },
            { name: '750,000', value: '750000' },
            { name: '800,000', value: '800000' },
            { name: '900,000', value: '900000' },
            { name: '950,000', value: '950000' },
            { name: '1,000,000', value: '1000000' },
            { name: '1,500,000', value: '1500000' },
            { name: '1,600,000', value: '1600000' },
            { name: '1,700,000', value: '1700000' },
            { name: '1,800,000', value: '1800000' },
            { name: '1,900,000', value: '1900000' },
            { name: '2,000,000', value: '2000000' },
        ],
        placeholder: 'Max Price(USD)',
        queryName: 'maxPrice',
    },
    {
        items: [
            { name: 'Lowest Price', value: 'price-asc' },
            { name: 'Highest Price', value: 'price-des' },
            { name: 'Newest', value: 'date-asc' },
            { name: 'Oldest', value: 'date-desc' },
        ],
        placeholder: 'Sort',
        queryName: 'sort',
    },
    {
        items: [
            { name: '1', value: '1' },
            { name: '2', value: '2' },
            { name: '3', value: '3' },
            { name: '4', value: '4' },
            { name: '5', value: '5' },
            { name: '6', value: '6' },
            { name: '7', value: '7' },
            { name: '8', value: '8' },
            { name: '9', value: '9' },
            { name: '10', value: '10' },
        ],
        placeholder: 'Rooms',
        queryName: 'roomsMin',
    },
    {
        items: [
            { name: '1', value: '1' },
            { name: '2', value: '2' },
            { name: '3', value: '3' },
            { name: '4', value: '4' },
            { name: '5', value: '5' },
            { name: '6', value: '6' },
            { name: '7', value: '7' },
            { name: '8', value: '8' },
            { name: '9', value: '9' },
            { name: '10', value: '10' },
        ],
        placeholder: 'Baths',
        queryName: 'bathsMin'
    },
  ];

export const getFilterValues = (filterValues) => {
    const {
        minPrice,
        maxPrice,
        sort,
        roomsMin,
        bathsMin,
    } = filterValues;

    const values = [
        {
            name: 'minPrice',
            value: minPrice,
        },
        {
            name: 'maxPrice',
            value: maxPrice,
        },
        {
            name: 'sort',
            value: sort,
        },
        {
            name: 'roomsMin',
            value: roomsMin,
        },
        {
            name: 'bathsMin',
            value: bathsMin,
        },
    ];

    return values;
}
```

And now I am not sure how I #1 can display them and #2 how to put them in effect, so that when for example min price is chosen that all properties from that price and up are shown.

I do understand that I have to call on the values, but just not sure how to put them in display and how to put them in effect.

This is sample data that I want to be filterd:

```
import PropertyPic from "../assets/images/propertyImage.jpeg";
import BedroomImage from "../assets/icons/icons8-sleeping-in-bed-100.png";
import BathroomImage from "../assets/icons/icons8-shower-80.png";
import SqftImage from "../assets/icons/sqft-img.png";

const PropertyData = [
    {
        id:"1",
        listingType:"Buy",
        type:"Villa",
        image:PropertyPic,
        heading:"Comfortable Apartment in Sint Maarten",
        description:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, illoat. Repudiandae ratione impedit delectus consectetur. Aspernaturvero obcaecati placeat ab distinctio unde ipsam molestias atqueratione delectus blanditiis nemo eius dignissimos doloremque quaealiquid maiores id tempore consequatur, quod pariatur saepe.',
        price:" $1.000.000",
        address:"Lot 644 Rue Dufy Terres Basses Saint Martin, 97150, Saint-Martin",
        location:"Sint Maarten",
        surfaceImage:SqftImage,
        surface:"1200 Sqft",
        bedrooms:"3 Beds",
        bedImage:BedroomImage,
        bath:"2 Bathroom",
        bathImage:BathroomImage
    },
    {
        id:"2",
        type:"Appartment",
        listingType:"Buy",
        image:PropertyPic,
        heading:"Comfortable Apartment in Sint Maarten",
        description:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, illoat. Repudiandae ratione impedit delectus consectetur. Aspernaturvero obcaecati placeat ab distinctio unde ipsam molestias atqueratione delectus blanditiis nemo eius dignissimos doloremque quaealiquid maiores id tempore consequatur, quod pariatur saepe.',
        price:" $200.000",
        address:"Lot 644 Rue Dufy Terres Basses Saint Martin, 97150",
        Location:"Sint Maarten",
        surfaceImage:SqftImage,
        surface:"1200 Sqft",
        bedrooms:"3 Beds",
        bedImage:BedroomImage,
        bath:"2 Bathroom",
        bathImage:BathroomImage
    },
    {
        id:"3",
        type:"Villa",
        listingType:"Rent",
        image:PropertyPic,
        heading:"Comfortable Apartment in Sint Maarten",
        description:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, illoat. Repudiandae ratione impedit delectus consectetur. Aspernaturvero obcaecati placeat ab distinctio unde ipsam molestias atqueratione delectus blanditiis nemo eius dignissimos doloremque quaealiquid maiores id tempore consequatur, quod pariatur saepe.',
        price:" $10.000",
        address:"Lot 644 Rue Dufy Terres Basses Saint Martin, 97150, Saint-Martin",
        Location:"Sint Maarten",
        surfaceImage:SqftImage,
        surface:"1200 Sqft",
        bedrooms:"3 Beds",
        bedImage:BedroomImage,
        bath:"2 Bathroom",
        bathImage:BathroomImage
    },
    {
        id:"4",
        type:"Villa",
        listingType:"Buy",
        image:PropertyPic,
        heading:"Comfortable Villa in Sint Maarten",
        description:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, illoat. Repudiandae ratione impedit delectus consectetur. Aspernaturvero obcaecati placeat ab distinctio unde ipsam molestias atqueratione delectus blanditiis nemo eius dignissimos doloremque quaealiquid maiores id tempore consequatur, quod pariatur saepe.',
        price:" $450.000",
        address:"Simpson Bay Yacht Club 12-3, 97150, Saint-Martin",
        Location:"Sint Maarten",
        surfaceImage:SqftImage,
        surface:"1200 Sqft",
        bedrooms:"3 Beds",
        bedImage:BedroomImage,
        bath:"2 Bathroom",
        bathImage:BathroomImage
    },
    {
        id:"5",
        type:"House",
        listingType:"Rent",
        image:PropertyPic,
        heading:"Comfortable Apartment in Sint Maarten",
        description:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, illoat. Repudiandae ratione impedit delectus consectetur. Aspernaturvero obcaecati placeat ab distinctio unde ipsam molestias atqueratione delectus blanditiis nemo eius dignissimos doloremque quaealiquid maiores id tempore consequatur, quod pariatur saepe.',
        price:" $1.000.000",
        address:"Lot 644 Rue Dufy Terres Basses Saint Martin, 97150, Saint-Martin",
        surfaceImage:SqftImage,
        surface:"1200 Sqft",
        bedrooms:"3 Beds",
        bedImage:BedroomImage,
        bath:"2 Bathroom",
        bathImage:BathroomImage
    },
    {
        id:"6",
        type:"Appartment",
        listingType:"Rent",
        image:PropertyPic,
        heading:"Comfortable Apartment in Sint Maarten",
        description:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, illoat. Repudiandae ratione impedit delectus consectetur. Aspernaturvero obcaecati placeat ab distinctio unde ipsam molestias atqueratione delectus blanditiis nemo eius dignissimos doloremque quaealiquid maiores id tempore consequatur, quod pariatur saepe.',
        price:" $2000",
        address:"Lot 644 Rue Dufy Terres Basses Saint Martin, 97150, Saint-Martin",
        surfaceImage:SqftImage,
        surface:"1200 Sqft",
        bedrooms:"3 Beds",
        bedImage:BedroomImage,
        bath:"2 Bathroom",
        bathImage:BathroomImage
    },
    {
        id:"7",
        type:"Villa",
        listingType:"Buy",
        image:PropertyPic,
        heading:"Comfortable Apartment in Sint Maarten",
        description:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, illoat. Repudiandae ratione impedit delectus consectetur. Aspernaturvero obcaecati placeat ab distinctio unde ipsam molestias atqueratione delectus blanditiis nemo eius dignissimos doloremque quaealiquid maiores id tempore consequatur, quod pariatur saepe.',
        price:" $1.000.000",
        address:"Lot 644 Rue Dufy Terres Basses Saint Martin, 97150, Saint-Martin",
        surfaceImage:SqftImage,
        surface:"1200 Sqft",
        bedrooms:"3 Beds",
        bedImage:BedroomImage,
        bath:"2 Bathroom",
        bathImage:BathroomImage
    },
    {
        id:"8",
        type:"Villa",
        listingType:"Buy",
        image:PropertyPic,
        heading:"Comfortable Apartment in Sint Maarten",
        description:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, illoat. Repudiandae ratione impedit delectus consectetur. Aspernaturvero obcaecati placeat ab distinctio unde ipsam molestias atqueratione delectus blanditiis nemo eius dignissimos doloremque quaealiquid maiores id tempore consequatur, quod pariatur saepe.',
        price:" $1.000.000",
        address:"Lot 644 Rue Dufy Terres Basses Saint Martin, 97150, Saint-Martin",
        surfaceImage:SqftImage,
        surface:"1200 Sqft",
        bedrooms:"3 Beds",
        bedImage:BedroomImage,
        bath:"2 Bathroom",
        bathImage:BathroomImage
    }
]
export default PropertyData;
```

Comment: do you have any sample data to be used for filtering, if so add them to the question

Comment: Yess sorry, just added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `FilterInput` for all filter selections and keep a state for all filters and another `renderFilteredData` function to do the filtering.

You can start like this:

```js
const filterDataBuy = [ { items: [ { name: "150,000", value: "150000" }, { name: "200,000", value: "200000" }, { name: "250,000", value: "250000" }, { name: "300,000", value: "300000" }, { name: "350,000", value: "350000" }, { name: "400,000", value: "400000" }, { name: "450,000", value: "450000" }, { name: "500,000", value: "500000" } ], placeholder: "Min Price(USD)", queryName: "minPrice" }, { items: [ { name: "500,000", value: "500000" }, { name: "550,000", value: "550000" }, { name: "600,000", value: "600000" }, { name: "650,000", value: "650000" }, { name: "700,000", value: "700000" }, { name: "750,000", value: "750000" }, { name: "800,000", value: "800000" }, { name: "900,000", value: "900000" }, { name: "950,000", value: "950000" }, { name: "1,000,000", value: "1000000" }, { name: "1,500,000", value: "1500000" }, { name: "1,600,000", value: "1600000" }, { name: "1,700,000", value: "1700000" }, { name: "1,800,000", value: "1800000" }, { name: "1,900,000", value: "1900000" }, { name: "2,000,000", value: "2000000" } ], placeholder: "Max Price(USD)", queryName: "maxPrice" }, { items: [ { name: "Lowest Price", value: "price-asc" }, { name: "Highest Price", value: "price-des" }, { name: "Newest", value: "date-asc" }, { name: "Oldest", value: "date-desc" } ], placeholder: "Sort", queryName: "sort" }, { items: [ { name: "1", value: "1" }, { name: "2", value: "2" }, { name: "3", value: "3" }, { name: "4", value: "4" }, { name: "5", value: "5" }, { name: "6", value: "6" }, { name: "7", value: "7" }, { name: "8", value: "8" }, { name: "9", value: "9" }, { name: "10", value: "10" } ], placeholder: "Rooms", queryName: "roomsMin" }, { items: [ { name: "1", value: "1" }, { name: "2", value: "2" }, { name: "3", value: "3" }, { name: "4", value: "4" }, { name: "5", value: "5" }, { name: "6", value: "6" }, { name: "7", value: "7" }, { name: "8", value: "8" }, { name: "9", value: "9" }, { name: "10", value: "10" } ], placeholder: "Baths", queryName: "bathsMin" } ]; const PropertyData = [ { id: "1", listingType: "Buy", type: "Villa", heading: "Comfortable Apartment in Sint Maarten", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, illoat. Repudiandae ratione impedit delectus consectetur. Aspernaturvero obcaecati placeat ab distinctio unde ipsam molestias atqueratione delectus blanditiis nemo eius dignissimos doloremque quaealiquid maiores id tempore consequatur, quod pariatur saepe.", price: " $1.000.000", address: "Lot 644 Rue Dufy Terres Basses Saint Martin, 97150, Saint-Martin", location: "Sint Maarten", surface: "1200 Sqft", bedrooms: "3 Beds", bath: "2 Bathroom" }, { id: "2", type: "Appartment", listingType: "Buy", heading: "Comfortable Apartment in Sint Maarten", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, illoat. Repudiandae ratione impedit delectus consectetur. Aspernaturvero obcaecati placeat ab distinctio unde ipsam molestias atqueratione delectus blanditiis nemo eius dignissimos doloremque quaealiquid maiores id tempore consequatur, quod pariatur saepe.", price: " $200.000", address: "Lot 644 Rue Dufy Terres Basses Saint Martin, 97150", Location: "Sint Maarten", surface: "1200 Sqft", bedrooms: "3 Beds", bath: "2 Bathroom" }, { id: "3", type: "Villa", listingType: "Rent", heading: "Comfortable Apartment in Sint Maarten", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, illoat. Repudiandae ratione impedit delectus consectetur. Aspernaturvero obcaecati placeat ab distinctio unde ipsam molestias atqueratione delectus blanditiis nemo eius dignissimos doloremque quaealiquid maiores id tempore consequatur, quod pariatur saepe.", price: " $10.000", address: "Lot 644 Rue Dufy Terres Basses Saint Martin, 97150, Saint-Martin", Location: "Sint Maarten", surface: "1200 Sqft", bedrooms: "3 Beds", bath: "2 Bathroom" }, { id: "4", type: "Villa", listingType: "Buy", heading: "Comfortable Villa in Sint Maarten", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, illoat. Repudiandae ratione impedit delectus consectetur. Aspernaturvero obcaecati placeat ab distinctio unde ipsam molestias atqueratione delectus blanditiis nemo eius dignissimos doloremque quaealiquid maiores id tempore consequatur, quod pariatur saepe.", price: " $450.000", address: "Simpson Bay Yacht Club 12-3, 97150, Saint-Martin", Location: "Sint Maarten", surface: "1200 Sqft", bedrooms: "3 Beds", bath: "2 Bathroom" }, { id: "5", type: "House", listingType: "Rent", heading: "Comfortable Apartment in Sint Maarten", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, illoat. Repudiandae ratione impedit delectus consectetur. Aspernaturvero obcaecati placeat ab distinctio unde ipsam molestias atqueratione delectus blanditiis nemo eius dignissimos doloremque quaealiquid maiores id tempore consequatur, quod pariatur saepe.", price: " $1.000.000", address: "Lot 644 Rue Dufy Terres Basses Saint Martin, 97150, Saint-Martin", surface: "1200 Sqft", bedrooms: "3 Beds", bath: "2 Bathroom" }, { id: "6", type: "Appartment", listingType: "Rent", heading: "Comfortable Apartment in Sint Maarten", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, illoat. Repudiandae ratione impedit delectus consectetur. Aspernaturvero obcaecati placeat ab distinctio unde ipsam molestias atqueratione delectus blanditiis nemo eius dignissimos doloremque quaealiquid maiores id tempore consequatur, quod pariatur saepe.", price: " $2000", address: "Lot 644 Rue Dufy Terres Basses Saint Martin, 97150, Saint-Martin", surface: "1200 Sqft", bedrooms: "3 Beds", bath: "2 Bathroom" }, { id: "7", type: "Villa", listingType: "Buy", heading: "Comfortable Apartment in Sint Maarten", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, illoat. Repudiandae ratione impedit delectus consectetur. Aspernaturvero obcaecati placeat ab distinctio unde ipsam molestias atqueratione delectus blanditiis nemo eius dignissimos doloremque quaealiquid maiores id tempore consequatur, quod pariatur saepe.", price: " $1.000.000", address: "Lot 644 Rue Dufy Terres Basses Saint Martin, 97150, Saint-Martin", surface: "1200 Sqft", bedrooms: "3 Beds", bath: "2 Bathroom" }, { id: "8", type: "Villa", listingType: "Buy", heading: "Comfortable Apartment in Sint Maarten", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, illoat. Repudiandae ratione impedit delectus consectetur. Aspernaturvero obcaecati placeat ab distinctio unde ipsam molestias atqueratione delectus blanditiis nemo eius dignissimos doloremque quaealiquid maiores id tempore consequatur, quod pariatur saepe.", price: " $1.000.000", address: "Lot 644 Rue Dufy Terres Basses Saint Martin, 97150, Saint-Martin", surface: "1200 Sqft", bedrooms: "3 Beds", bath: "2 Bathroom" } ];

const renderFilteredData = (propertyData, filterState) => {
  const filtered = propertyData.filter(({ price, bath, bedrooms }) => {
    let valid = true;
    const minPriceNum = Number(filterState.minPrice);
    const maxPriceNum = Number(filterState.maxPrice);
    const priceNum = Number(price.replace(/[^\d]+/g, ""));

    // filter price
    valid = valid && priceNum >= minPriceNum && priceNum <= maxPriceNum;

    const bathsNum = Number(bath.replace(/[^\d]+/g, ""));
    const bedsNum = Number(bedrooms.replace(/[^\d]+/g, ""));
    const bathsMin = Number(filterState.bathsMin);
    const roomsMin = Number(filterState.roomsMin);

    // filter baths and beds
    valid = valid && bathsNum >= bathsMin && bedsNum >= roomsMin;

    return valid;
  });

  // do the sorting here, not realted to filtering
  // it's about how to view the filtered data

  return filtered.map(({ id, heading, price, bath, bedrooms }) => (
    <div
      style={{ border: "solid 1px", padding: "5px", margin: "5px" }}
      key={id}
    >
      <h4>{heading}</h4>
      <h5>{price}</h5>
      <div>bath rooms: {bath}</div>
      <div>bed rooms: {bedrooms}</div>
    </div>
  ));
};

const FilterInput = ({
  items,
  placeholder,
  queryName,
  handleFilterChange,
  value
}) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    handleFilterChange(queryName, items[0].value);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ marginBottom: "15px" }}>
      <label htmlFor={placeholder}>{placeholder}</label>
      <br />
      <select
        id={placeholder}
        value={value}
        onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
          handleFilterChange(queryName, value);
        }}
      >
        {items.map(({ name, value }) => (
          <option value={value} key={name}>
            {name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [filterState, setFilterState] = React.useState({});

  const handleFilterChange = React.useCallback((queryName, value) => {
    setFilterState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [queryName]: value
    }));
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {}, [filterState]);

  return (
    <div>
      {filterDataBuy.map(({ items, placeholder, queryName }) => (
        <FilterInput
          key={queryName}
          items={items}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          queryName={queryName}
          handleFilterChange={handleFilterChange}
          value={filterState[queryName]}
        />
      ))}
      <div>{renderFilteredData(PropertyData, filterState)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

NOTE: Ideally you should call a backend endpoint with the filter state to do the data filtering.

Comment: @Its.Chelle, check this out !! Let me know if you want any clarifications